# User configuration settings made via gpedit not reflecting in registry for user with Logon as service right

Tags: windows-registry, user-accounts, group-policy, windows-server-2012

I am trying to enable screen saver setting via gpedit and also ran gpupdate and rebooted the server.

I have a Bigfix script that is iterating over HKEY_USERS hive and checking if a user key is present and it doesnt have the setting.

I can see some user SID entries that appear under HKEY_USERS but they do not have the settings i created. Those appear to be users that have never logged on to the server but have the Logon as service right. There are couple of services running as that user.

My question is whether those service users will not reflect the settings i make via gpedit? If not, is there a way to differentiate the HKEY_USER keys as to whether they belong to users that have logged in versus users that have the Login as a service right?

Thanks.